# NSNull Exception in iphone app in Cell for Row at index

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

```
     cell.theTitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetical Bold" size:14];
     cell.theTitle.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theCellData.contentTitle];
 cell.theDescriptionLabel.text=theCellData.contentTitle;
 cell.theDateAdded.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Added: %@",theCellData.contentAddedDateTime];


 NSString*type=theCellData.contentType;


 NSLog(@"type is %@",type);


 if ([type isEqualToString:@"Video"]) {

     [cell.theCellImageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video icon.png",indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


 }
else if ([type isEqualToString:@"Audio"]) {




    NSLog(@"Audio");
      [cell.theCellImageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sound icon.png",indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}
else {


    [cell.theCellImageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"20.png",indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}




[cell.theCellImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.theCellImageButton setTag:indexPath.row];




 return cell;
```

here is the crash log

type is Audio
2013-06-14 16:09:50.071 ProductivoApp[6516:c503] Audio
2013-06-14 16:09:50.076 ProductivoApp[6516:c503] -[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x125adc8
2013-06-14 16:09:50.079 ProductivoApp[6516:c503] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x125adc8'

Comment: it clearly says that String is nil/Null

Comment: theCellData.contentType coming null maybe thats the prob

Comment: it was working fine if it is nill then how in NSLOg it shows Audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `type` string is not equal to either `Audio` or `Video`.When that crash occurs, type is referring to an instance of `NSNull`.
for more info try to print this you will get this `NSNull`.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [type class]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is getting null values. So while comparing the variable type its showing error

```
 NSString*type=theCellData.contentType;// is null
if ([type isEqualToString:@"Video"]) //error at this line
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you are comparing is null. Try adding:
//only do if not null
if (string){

if ([type isEqualToString:@"Video"]) {

```
 [cell.theCellImageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video icon.png",indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}
else if ([type isEqualToString:@"Audio"]) {

```
NSLog(@"Audio");
  [cell.theCellImageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sound icon.png",indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}
else {

```
[cell.theCellImageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"20.png",indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

}

This will make sure no null comparisons happen

Comment: Basically just surround that part of the code with if (string). This is shorthand for (string!=null)